# Version comparison and perform the sequential deployment of version in Groovy (Jenkins file)

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, dsl, jenkins-groovy

I am doing below task in jenkinsfile using groovy.

```
1-I am doing git tag on a repository "DATABASE_REPOSITORY" where the tags comes like below
def GITTAG_VERSION = sh(script:""" git tag --sort=v:refname """, returnStdout:true).trim()
FS2_UP_1.7
FS2_UP_1.9
FS2_UP_1.10
FS2_UP_1.0.1
FS2_UP_1.0.10
FS2_UP_1.0.17
FS2_UP_1.1.1
FS2_UP_2.0.1
```

2- I am running a sql statement, which gives deployed version on server example DEPLOYED_VERSION=FS2_UP_1.1.1

3- and i am passing as input USERINPUTVERSION=FS2_UP_1.10 from JENKINS build with parameter ,

So i have three values 1) GITTAG_VERSION  2) DEPLOYED_VERSION  3)USERINPUTVERSION

```
1) Now i am trying to achive if the 
${USERINPUTVERSION} == ${DEPLOYED_VERSION}
echo " provided version is latest deployed version. do nothing."
```

2. not equal to.

```
${USERINPUTVERSION} != ${DEPLOYED_VERSION}
echo " provided input version is notmatched in DEPLOYED_VERSION"
then go and check the GITTAG_VERSION and deploy in sequense.
```

example:-

```
USERINPUTVERSION=FS2_UP_1.10  != DEPLOYED_VERSION=FS2_UP_1.1.1
then check GITTAG_VERSION
USERINPUTVERSION=FS2_UOP_1.10 is in the 3rd position of git tag list (here i have to use loop to iterate the GITTAG_VERSION)
echo "deploying version FS2_UP_1.10"
echo "deploying version FS2_UP_1.0.1"
echo "deploying version FS2_UP_1.0.10"
echo "deploying version FS2_UP_1.0.17"
echo "Latest version FS2_UP_1.1.1 is deployed"
```

I am new to Programming groovy, can someone please help how to iterate this and deploy the expected version.

Here is my code,

```
def A = sh(script: """
cd "${GIT_REPO}"/
git tag --sort=v:refname
""", returnStdout: true).trim()

def list = []
list.add("${A}")
echo "${list}"
env.VERSION_REQUIRED = GITTAG_VERSION.replace("FS2_UP_","")

def getVersion = list.get(0)
getVersion.eachMatch(VERSION_REQUIRED){
   versionRequired -> println versionRequired
echo "${C} is Available in the list}

env.LATEST_VERSION = DEPLOYED_VERSION.replace("FS2_UP_","")
 
echo "Current Version is ${LATEST_VERSION}"

if ("${versionRequired}" == "${LATEST_VERSION}") {
      echo "Do not deploy Schema"
} else if ("${versionRequired}" != "${LATEST_VERSION}") {
     for (i = "${versionRequired}"; i < "${LATEST_VERSION}"; i++) {
    println("${i}")
 }
}
```

Comment: Please show actual Groovy code you have tried to write, not pseudo code. From pseudo code I can't see what you are actually having trouble with. Please include output and any error message.

Comment: @zett42 - I have added my code. can you please take a look and suggest your input. Appreciate your help.